# I need to append the test results of different VSTest tasks in to the same folder in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i am running 2 vstest tasks, one is to test assemblies and other to run integration tests in azure pipelines. And am storing the results of both tests in same folder 'TestResults'.
below is the yaml script for that.

```
    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*tests.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
          !**\moq.dll
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        otherConsoleOptions: '--collect:"Code Coverage"'
        resultsFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SiprotecUnitTestSolution\TestResults'

    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'ITTest'
      inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*tests.IT.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
          !**\moq.dll
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        otherConsoleOptions: '--collect:"Code Coverage"'
        codeCoverageEnabled: true
        resultsFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SiprotecUnitTestSolution\TestResult'
```

But I feel the results of  one task is over writing the results from other task. I need the test results from both the tasks in the same folder(TestResult), so that I can generate the code coverage report for that folder. Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you check under the exported folder what files are inside? you could use a powershell task after your second test task and use `ls '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SiprotecUnitTestSolution\TestResults'`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you let me know like how to code this powershell task and what need to be done?

Comment: After your task with displayname `ITTest` you should add a powershell task `task: PowerShell@2` with the command `ls` under `'$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SiprotecUnitTestSolution\TestResults'`

Comment: sorry, could you please type entire code of powershell task, as it is new for me.-  is it like this-                                                                                                          
            powershell: |
            write-host "Appending IT test results !!!!!"
            ls '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SiprotecUnitTestSolution\TestResults'            
           displayName: 'Append test results'

Comment: I pasted the code https://www.codepile.net/pile/r67BYVg5 not to spam the original question.